# Get updated size of QGraphicsView

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qgraphicsview

In my Qt Application I am dynamically creating [QGraphicsView](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qgraphicsview.html)(s) and adding them inside
a [QGridLayout](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qgridlayout.html).
When I add first view inside grid, the view covers all the available space inside grid.
Then I add second view and there are now two equally sized views inside grid.
Then I add third view and there are now three equally sized views inside grid.
And so on.

How can I get updated size of first view?

Below is my trial but I think this is not working.

```
//Definition of viewsPerRow
 static const int viewsPerRow = 3;
 void window::newViewRequested()
 {
     QGraphicsView *view = new QGraphicsView;
     view->setVisible(true);
     viewVector.push_back(view);

     for(int i = viewGrid->count(); i < viewVector.count(); i++)
     {
       viewGrid->addWidget(view,i / viewsPerRow ,i % viewsPerRow);
     }
      qDebug()<<viewGrid->cellRect(0,0);
    }
```

Comment: One problem we've run into in the past is that they layouts may delay resizing any of the widgets until they need to; usually right before they draw.  So getting the size from the widgets in the layout may not be correct until the layout has been done.  I believe there's a function to cause the layout resizing to happen, but don't recall what it is offhand.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the size?  cjhuitt is right, generally the layout does not correct the size until it needs to.  You are probably doing something you shouldn't if you need to synchronously get the size after the layout fixes itself.  However, if you really want to do this, call viewGrid->activate() after you add the widgets to force it to redo the layout.

Comment: No serious aim, just trying to learn Qt Framework. But  viewGrid->activate() does not work.

Comment: If you still really want to do this, try forcing a paint on the top level widget.  Again, it might not work.  Qt does as few updates as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should use the `QWidget::rect()` methods to get the geometry of the views themselves. Here is a sample that should work as intended.

```
QVector< QGraphicsView* > views;
for (int i=0 ; i < 3; ++i) {
  QGraphicsView *view = new QGraphicsView;
  view->setVisible(true);
  viewGrid->addWidget(view, i ,0);
  views.push_back(view);
}

qDebug() << "The view size of the first view is " << views[0]->rect();
```

Comment: I tried your code. When I added first view I got default size of the QGraphicsView which is 256 x 192. When I added the second view I got calculated size but this time calculation was wrong(I think it considers there exist only one view). When I added the third one I got wrong calculated size again(This time I think it considers there exists two views)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need the size of the first view, but Qt does only few redraws at the time it "thinks" it is suited. Therefore you can't rely on a size you query outside the view.

I'd try to use the [resizeEvent](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qgraphicsview.html#resizeEvent) to get notified when the size of an item changes and perform the necessary actions then.